# user input not saving to file

Tags: c, file, fopen, fclose

so i created 2 text file where my user and staff data respectively can be stored but my data doesn't get stored but the code is running perfectly.
This is my code

```c
FILE *usr;
FILE *staf;
usr = fopen("users.txt","a+");
staf = fopen("staff.txt","a+");
char choice;

// some data to be collected

if (choice == 's')
{
fscanf(staf,"staffs: %d/%d/%d %s %s %s %s %d\n ",add.month,add.day,add.year,add.name,add.staff.username,add.password,add.email,add.number);
    fprintf(staf,"staffs: %d/%d/%d %s %s %s %s %d\n ",add.month,add.day,add.year,add.name,add.staff.username,add.password,add.email,add.number);
    fclose(staf);
}
else if (choice == 'u')
{
fscanf(usr,"staffs: %d/%d/%d %s %s %s %s %d\n ",add.month,add.day,add.year,add.name,add.user.username,add.password,add.email,add.number);
    fprintf(usr," %d/%d/%d %s %s %s %s %d\n",add.month,add.day,add.year,add.name,add.user.username,add.password,add.email,add.number);
    fclose(usr);   
}
else
{
    goto personnel;
}
```

Comment: I think that the error is the use of `&` with printf (or family)

Comment: Turn up the warning level in your compiler, it should complain about your `fprintf()` calls.

Comment: As Barmar mentioned, increase the warning level on your compiles (e.g. use `-Wall -O2`) and your `fprintf` will be flagged: It will see what Eduardo saw.

Comment: It's hard to know what is correct, since you haven't shown the relevant declarations, but if `choice` is an `int` (which it seems it is given `choice == 'u'`), then printing it with `%s` is certainly wrong.  If `choice` is a char *, then both `choice == 's'` and `choice == 'u'` will be false.

Comment: @WilliamPursell choice is a char

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff i took out the & and it still not reflecting on the files but the files were created

Comment: if `choice ` is a char, then using `%s` format string in `fprintf` is incorrect.  If there is a scanf that isn't shown that is using `%s`, that would be problematic.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 substitutions of your `fprintf()` don't match up. `%d` is used for integers, you pass a pointer to it. Also, I don't know for sure, but I doubt you want to print the pointer to a file. If you do however, use `%p`. For more information, try `man 3 printf`.